# Repository pattern, should it be 1:1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I'm currently working on a project in which I'm using the Repository Pattern.  Currently for each table in my db, I'm building out a repository.  As the db grows this is becoming a bit tedious, and i'm wondering if I need to do is for each table.  The users have requested the ability to edit all tables, including those which are just used in dropdowns.  For example, we have a SubContractor table, which has a link to a WorkLocation table.  SubContractors also have a link to a TypeOfWork table, that section alone has me building out 3 repositories.  I initially thought of only building a SubContractor one, but again the users would like to edit any of them, so we built each one a repository.  Is this common?

Comment: Don't you have some sort of a generic base repo for basic CRUD operations?

Comment: Generics are your friend! You can create a `Repository<T>` where `T` is an entity type (i.e., an object that represents a table entry).

Comment: will look into generics!

Comment: This article might help if you're using EF: ["Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (you might need to jump down to the "Implement a Generic Repository and a Unit of Work Class"  chapter).

Comment: The generics part is nice, but you may also want to update to DbContext to handle more complex Unit of Work scenarios with relations between tables, and transactional updates between multiple tables.

Comment: DBContext's DBSets _are_ the repositories. Do not wrap them for the sake of wrapping. Repository pattern was useful in the good ol days when ORM frameworks didn't exist.

Comment: @Mrchief I'm not agree. Repository pattern is still required because you don't want to couple your domain with a specific OR/M. The OR/M (the data mapper) is what repository encapsulates.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: It is going to be a leaky abstraction anyway. You won't be able to decouple them completely. And honestly, this is the same argument that we had in old days - what if I want to replace my Oracle Data Provider with Sql Server provider? Seriously, how often does that happen?

Comment: @Mrchief: apart from Matias wrote (I agree that the chances of changing the ORM for a single project are slim), there are cases when having this extra layer can sometimes save you ass: injecting the actual repo implementation (even if it's a wrapper on top of `DbSet` 99% of the time) as a dependency allows you to tweak that 1% of poorly-performant queries if needed and even introduce a bunch of functionality transparently if needed. We had a project where we had to add multitenancy in the middle of a project, for example. Try to do that with `DbSet`s scattered around your code.

Comment: @Groo: Won't you have to do the same in case of repositories as well? And if you're talking about removing code duplication (define the query in one place, use in many), there are many ways to do that but creating an extra layer every time so that you may use it 1% of the time doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Mrchief I've been able to design/implement a non-leaky abstraction and I'm able to switch from one OR/M to another, or even, switch to Redis with few or zero effort. I know that a project mightn't change to another OR/M (chances are near to zero), but if you want to build a framework, having the chance to use 2, 3 or 4 different OR/M techs depending on the project using that framework is a big win

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Its a classic case of YAGNI. I've fallen to its trap several times. Now-a-days, unless I'm building prototypes or Proof-Of-Concepts, I seldom see the value of building something that has almost zero chances of getting used. Taking the layer away also means I can exploit the strengths of the specific ORM I'm targetting, and not confine myself to a generic but less powerful implementation. On the other side, I'm very interested to see your implementation. Any chance you can post the relevant bits somewhere?

Comment: @Mrchief The chance is I would love to publish it in GitHub. This requires documentation. Anyway, I believe a project has zero chance of changing the OR/M tech, but a framework that provides domain abstractions should be able to support more than an OR/M, and without losing the power of each specific OR/M.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: So you're saying that your code is not descriptive enough or I'm not competent enough to understand it, that it needs the crutches of **documentation**? :) Let me when you do, I'll read it with or w/o documentation anyway!

Comment: @Mrchief No, I mean that *some* quickstart documentation might be required, because it implements IoC using Castle Windsor and you should know about how to configure built-in components, blah blah... :\ Sure, it might come with a default configuration-by-code configuration....

Comment: @Mrchief: but what happens when you do need to optimize a query? Do you just hack a couple of SQL strings in your domain/business layer? I am not really sure what you mean by *DBSets are the repositories*, it's possible I didn't understand. And as I wrote, using the repository from the start, we were able to introduce multitenancy completely transparently. Domain layer now gets (the same) a unit of work instance injected (or, instantiates is through a service locator), and the instance manages appropriate connections under the hood. For the domain layer, it seems like a single database.

Comment: @Groo: See my [answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/17513/5694). Another good [article](http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) here. As far as optimizations go, EF is ususally pretty good at generating far better queries than what an average developer may come up with. Brushing that aside, if you need to, you can still replace your query with a stored procedure for absolute control. If you use command-query-separation pattern, this can happen in your command/query and still wouldn't pollute your business layer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't create a repository-per-table, because a repository is pattern to encapsulate how domain objects get translated to another data representation (for example, a relational database), and also translates them again into domain objects.

First of all, 1 table may or may not be 1 domain object. OR/M frameworks like Entity Framework or NHibernate are more than just mapping objects to tables.

A domain object might have associations with other domain objects of the same domain, and this means that a domain object might be persisted to one or more tables depending on the relational design behind the repository.

Also, there's a common practice where you implement repositories for *root* entities only. For example, there's an `Company` domain object which has many `Employee`. You should design a `ICompanyRepository` and code an implementation on top of your favourite OR/M, and `Employee` creation would be done by adding employees to `Company.Employees` *1-n* association:

```
ICompanyRepository repo = new CompanyRepositoryImplementation();
Company myCompany = repo.GetById(839984);
myCompany.Employees.Add(new Employee { FullName = "Matias Fidemraizer" });
```

A good full OR/M like Entity Framework or NHibernate will persist associations and the simple act of adding an employee to `Employees` association will issue an `INSERT` to create the whole employee, and you'll be able to query and obtain that employee using LINQ (or any other object query approach).

Finally, you should try to implement a generic repository where `GetById`, `GetByCriteria` (custom criteria using an expression tree/LINQ), `Add` and `Remove` (*no* `Update` please, this is also handled by OR/M transactions when you modify an object or collection) that both can be work *as is* or it can be derived in order to provide specific domain requirements.

Generic repository signature would look like the following sample:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TDomainObject>
   where TDomainObject : DomainObject
```